# How to create a table in Moodle database automatically when installing a new plug-in in Moodle?

Tags: database, moodle

I create a new plug-in in report of courses in Moodle.
In my program, I need save some data in a new table in Moodle database.
Before it, I was creating that table manually and add data in code like this:

```
      global $DB;
      $record = new stdClass;

      $record->firstvalue=$firstvalue;
      $record->secondvalue=$secondvalue; 
      $record->courseid=$id;        
      $record->name= $fromform->name;
      $record->ytitle=$ytitle;
      $record->xtitle=$xtitle;
      $record->value=$values;

      $DB->insert_record('chart', $record);
```

But now, I need create that table automatically, when this plug-in install in another computer.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the xmldb editor to create an install.xml file to describe the database tables to be created during install.

If you also need to add default records during install, then you should put the instructions inside the install.php.

See https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Upgrade_API for full details about how to use the editor and what to put inside those files.